# AppDomain Creation : Resolving "Could not load file or assembly" error

Tags: c#, .net

This is just weird. Here's the code :

```
 AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("newDomain ", null,
            new AppDomainSetup
            {
                ApplicationBase = @"D:\myDLLFolderFullPath\"
            });

 Assembly a = newDomain.Load("myAssembly");
```

This throws the "Could not load file or assembly" error.
I checked my Assembly's dll is located under the specified folder path, and the name of the Assembly is correct.
When I copy myAssembly.dll into the CurrentDomain's main folder, it works !
It behaves as if the ApplicationBase setting for the new AppDomain has absolutely no effect and keep pointing to the Current AppDomain's AppBase.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Well, should work.  Watch out for dependent assemblies.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to diagnose the failed bind.

Comment: +1 for enabling fusion log binding and examining the results.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if .NET allows loading assemblies from paths that are not relative to the main executable path.

So, I think that this is not allowed:

```
 D:\myExeFolderFullPath\main.exe
 D:\myDLLFolderFullPath\Mydll.dll
```

...while this should work:

```
 D:\myExeFolderFullPath\main.exe
 D:\myExeFolderFullPath\myDLLFolderFullPath\Mydll.dll
```

**Update:**

I had a similar problem with paths when working on the [mygeneration](http://mygeneration.sourceforge.net) project. The only way I found to get it running was to reorganize the folder structure I described in this answer.

Comment: See also updated question. May be the reason for this has something to do with security. A highjacked application cann not reference other components outside the gac or its biniary folder. @Mika Jacobi: does your code work if the folders were reorganizised as i proposed?

Answer (score 1):

See msdn for **appDomain.load()** method:
*

> This method should be used only to load an assembly into the current
>   application domain.

- This method is provided as a convenience for interoperability callers who cannot call the static Assembly.Load method. To load assemblies into other application domains, use a method such as **CreateInstanceAndUnwrap**.
  If a version of the requested assembly is already loaded, this method returns the loaded assembly, even if a different version is requested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do exactly...

But to load a dll into an AppDomain and create an instance, you can do it like this:

Create a AppDomain. Setup and security info are optional parameters.

```
 var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("A friendly name to identify your application", null, null);
```

Load your assembly:

```
   var assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"C:\PathToYourApp\ConsoleApplication1.exe"));
```

Create an instance inside the app domain:

```
var instance = (Program)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assemblyName.Name, "ConsoleApplication1.Program");
```

Important: The class you want to unwrap and access outside of you app domain, had to be marked with the [Serializable] Attrbute!

```
[Serializable]
class Program{}
```

Use the event `appDomain.UnhandledException` for exception handling outside the AppDomain.

Comment: If that class is marked as [serializable] it will be pulled across the domain boundary, and the assembly it is defined in will be loaded into the parent domain.  If you are using appdomains to isolate assemblies, then `Program` (your example class) should extend MarshalByRefObject.  When you call CreateInstanceAndUnwrap, you will have a proxy to the type that exists within the second appdomain.